# Issue in sending email using Rails-4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue.I am trying to send an email to one user. there is no error showing in the code but it is unable to send email to the user.My code snippets are described below.Please check it and help me to run it successfully.

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Send email to your friend</h1>
<%= form_for @user,:url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field:name,placeholder:"Enter your name" %><br>
    <%= f.email_field:email,placeholder:"Enter your email" %><br>
    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

views/users/success.html.erb

```
<h1>Email sent successfully</h1>
```

views/users/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Successfully registered</h1>
```

controller/user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user=User.new
  end
  def create
    @user=User.new(users_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      redirect_to :action => 'success'
    else
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    end
  end
  def new

  end
  def success

  end
  private
  def users_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root 'users#index'
  post "users/create" => "users#create"
 get "users/success" => "users#success"
  get "users/new" => "users#new"
end
```

views/user_mailer/registration_confirmation.text.erb

```
<%= @user.name%>
<h1>Thank you for registering</h1>
Click <%= link_to "here",users_new_path %>
```

mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default :from => "w5call.w5rtc@gmail.com"
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user=user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")
  end
end
```

config/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => "w5call.w5rtc@gmail.com",
    :password             => "w5rtc123@",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

I was following this [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3?view=asciicast).I am using rails version 4.2.0 and ruby 1.9.3.Please help me to run it successfully.Thanks..

Comment: You are redirecting to index page or success after you submit form

Comment: Hello Dipak after submitting the input values will store in db and mail should send.If it will successfully saved and sent mail page will redirect to success.html.erb page otherwise it will stay in index page.So what is the solution for this problem.

Comment: Yes I saw that in code. You are redirecting in both cases that's why you are not getting error properly. Try `render :index` in your create action else part to see if you are getting any error or not

Comment: OK Dipak let me to do that and i will confirm you soon.

Comment: Relay thanks dipak to giving me such type of idea.Now it is showing some error at this particular line of create action("UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver") and the error is
Error:
Errno::ECONNREFUSED in UsersController#create
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)
Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: It's very simple. Please search on stackoverfolw you will get answer very easily

Comment: I followed one of the answer from stack overflow and it did not resolve my error.Any way thanks Dipak for such type of help.